# How can i send a different header id for every request with Artillery?

Tags: artillery

I'm trying to send for instance 1000 concurrent requests with different request-id header for performance testing. API will notify if a request-id is duplicated, I'm facing Artillery will use same request-id for most requests. Is there any config param i should add so I can avoid this?

```
config:
  plugins:
    expect: {}
  phases:
    - duration: 1 # Phase duration in seconds
      arrivalRate: 1000  # Initial number of virtual requests per second
      name: Warn up
  ensure:
    maxErrorRate: 0
  defaults:
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
      request-id: "request-{{ $randomString() }}"
```

- I tried to pass a .csv file as payload to set headers but it seems is not possible for headers to use that value.
- I tried to concatenate random string and number but I face the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the default headers config option. You can set headers on [each request](https://www.artillery.io/docs/reference/engines/http#setting-headers).

You should then be able to use the same mechanism you were using:

```yaml
scenarios:
  - flow:
      - get:
          url: "/"
          headers:
            request-id: "request-{{ $randomString() }}"
```

Alternatively, you can also use [custom javascript hooks](https://www.artillery.io/docs/reference/engines/http#beforerequest-hooks) to achieve something similar, but I think the above is the simplest way to get what you need.